# .Net Core JWT Authentication with custom API Key Middleware

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I have a .Net Core 2.0 application that uses JWT tokens to authorize the user.
This all works fine but I want to have some sort of API Key mechanism to allow other applications to integrate but I cannot seem to get this to work with the current authentication.

Code:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
            IMemoryCache cache, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    ApiKeyMiddlewear(app, serviceProvider);

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    { 
        routes.MapRoute(
               name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}


    private static void ApiKeyMiddlewear(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")))
            {
                // Let's check if this is an API Call
                if (context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"].Any())
                {
                    // validate the supplied API key
                    // Validate it
                    var headerKey = context.Request.Headers["ApiKey"].FirstOrDefault();
                    var settingsProvider = serviceProvider.GetService<ISettingsService<OmbiSettings>>();
                    var ombiSettings = settingsProvider.GetSettings();
                    var valid = ombiSettings.ApiKey.Equals(headerKey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                    if (!valid)
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid API Key");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var identity = new GenericIdentity("API");
                        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("Origin", "Api"));
                        identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("role", "Admin"));

                        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] {"ApiUser"});
                        context.User = principal;
                        await next();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So in the code above you can see that I am intercepting the HTTP requests that provide a header called ApiKey and then validate it to what I have stored. This part all works but when calling an API Method with the `Authorize` attribute this does not work and I get the following error logs:

```
2017-09-19 08:15:17.280 +01:00 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:52038/api/v1/Identity/ application/json 372
2017-09-19 08:15:21.967 +01:00 [Information] Authorization failed for user: "API".
2017-09-19 08:15:21.976 +01:00 [Information] Authorization failed for the request at filter '"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter"'.
2017-09-19 08:15:21.981 +01:00 [Information] Executing ForbidResult with authentication schemes ([]).
2017-09-19 08:15:21.991 +01:00 [Information] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was forbidden.
2017-09-19 08:15:21.996 +01:00 [Information] Executed action "Ombi.Controllers.IdentityController.CreateUser (Ombi)" in 38.8268ms
2017-09-19 08:15:22.004 +01:00 [Information] Request finished in 4723.032ms 403
```

Now I'm guessing this is to do with the request only supplying a `ApiKey` header and not a `Authorization` header with a correct JWT token.

How am I able to only supply a ApiKey header and when there is no ApiKey header then fallback to requiring a JWT token?

Comment: Are you using Asp.net Identity ?

Comment: @AramKocharyan Yes

Comment: Do you use `Authorize` attribute with `Roles` property ? Like `[Authorize(Roles = “foo”)]`

Comment: Applying `Claim("role", "Admin")` to `GenericPrincipal` will not affect anything, because `GenericPrincipal` have nothing to do with Claims. So if you want to apply admin role, you need to add it in constructor param: `new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] {"Admin", "ApiUser"});`

Comment: @AramKocharyan That works! If you don't mind putting an answer so I can grant you the bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applying `Claim("role", "Admin")` to `GenericPrincipal` will not affect anything, because `GenericPrincipal` have nothing to do with Role Claims. So if you want to apply admin role to `GenericPrincipal`, you need to add it in constructor parameter:

```
 var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] {"Admin","ApiUser"});
 context.User = principal;
```